# Outputting the score with only one function call

Tags: c++

I'm trying to check the score and outputting who ever wins. Black > 0, White < 0, and a tie being == 0. What should I do to see if GetValue(board) == 0 without calling my function again or using another variable?

```
GetValue(board) > 0 ? cout << "Black wins" : cout << "White wins";
```

Comment: Use a variable and take the code of BWG... it is a stupid constraint to keep you from doing it.

Comment: If the return values are only -1, 0 and 1, you could use a switch statement. Be aware there is no performance to be gained from not using a local variable.

Comment: Is it so important to use a single call?

Comment: @saadtaame yes, it is one of my teacher's constraints. I thought about doing a regular if(GetValue(board) == 0) but then I would need to use it again for else if getvalue(board) >0 . I'm not really sure how to approach it. If I set something like score = GetValue(board);, and I use score two times as what BWG answered, does that count as multiple calls?

Comment: That's a good way to do it. Store value in a variable and use the variable. It counts as a single call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you want to use a variable ? If you do, you can use a compound ternary operator :

```
int val = GetValue(board);
cout << val == 0 ? "Tie" : (val < 0 ? "White wins" : "Black wins");
```

Edit: But THAT isn't one line, is it? The REAL one liner, courtesy of lambda functions.
It also assumes that `GetValue` returns an int. And requires a `using namespace std` for conciseness.

```
cout << vector<string>({"White wins", "Tie", "Black Wins"})[([](int x){return(0<x)-(x<0)+1;}(GetValue(board)))];
```

(Also don't actually use that)

Comment: That is certainly a clever one-liner! However I wouldn't recommended it in practice, not just for readability, but also it allocates new strings each time. An std::array of const char * might be better.

Comment: @BWG Haha I didn't know the syntax of lambda expressions in C++ but that's true that from the moment you have functional programming you try to do anything with a single line, I do the same in Scala even if it is not always good for readability.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to output the score with one function call you can do something like:

```
cout << msg[ GetValue(board) + 1] << endl;
```

Where:

```
msg[0] = "White Wins";
msg[1] = "Tie";
msg[2] = "Black Wins";
```

This assumes that `GetValue` returns -1, 0, or 1;

Comment: I would rather use a switch statement in this case. Less to worry about if GetValue returns a bad value.

Comment: @NeilKirk I agree, he could just do `sign(GetValue(board))` so it "clamps" to -1/0/1

Comment: I agree. I don't know why OP wants a single function call :D

Answer (score 1):

```
std::string win_message(int const &x)
{
    if ( x == 0 ) return "Tie";
    if ( x < 0 ) return "Black wins";
    return "White wins";
}

// ...

    cout << win_message( GetValue(board) );
```

Comment: Why do you make it a reference?

Comment: @NeilKirk he specified to not use a variable